# Azure Data Studio does not recognize Kerberos Ticket in MacOS Monterey

Tags: sql-server, authentication, kerberos, macos-monterey, azure-data-studio

I am attempting to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database on a corporate network that is limited to Windows Authentication. I have configured Kerberos and Kerberos does successfully issue a ticket and I can verify that the ticket is valid in Ticket Viewer. But when I attempt to connect in Azure Data Studio, and select "Windows Authentication", I am given the message "Connection Failed due to Kerberos Error".

My krb5.conf is located at ~/etc/krb5.conf and I have followed configuration instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15).

On a Windows machine connected to the network, when I run `setspn -L DATABASENAME` I show:

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=DATABASENAME,OU=Servers,OU=Data Center,DC=companyname,DC=com:
        MSServerClusterMgmtAPI/DATABASENAME
        MSServerClusterMgmtAPI/DATABASENAME.companyname.com
        WSMAN/DATABASENAME
        WSMAN/DATABASENAME.companyname.com
        TERMSRV/DATABASENAME
        TERMSRV/DATABASENAME.companyname.com
        RestrictedKrbHost/DATABASENAME
        HOST/DATABASENAME
        RestrictedKrbHost/DATABASENAME.companyname.com
        HOST/DATABASENAME.companyname.com
```

When I run `nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.companyname.com` I show:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  xx.x.x.163
Non-authoritative answer:
_kerberos._tcp.companyname.com SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = dcname01.companyname.com
_kerberos._tcp.companyname.com SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = dcname02.companyname.com
_kerberos._tcp.companyname.com SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = dcname03.companyname.com
_kerberos._tcp.companyname.com SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = dcname04.companyname.com
dcname01.comapnyname.com        internet address = xx.x.x.47
dcname02.companyname.com        internet address = xx.x.x.8
dcname03.companyname.com        internet address = xx.xx.x.11
dcname04.companyname.com        internet address = xx.xx.x.10
```

The way I have my krb5.conf file configured is:

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = COMPANYNAME.COM

[realms]
COMPANYNAME.COM = {
 kdc = dcname01.companyname.com
 kdc = dcname02.companyname.com
 kdc = dcname03.companyname.com
 kdc = dcname04.companyname.com
}
```

I have tried many different configurations for krb5.conf involving inclusion and omission of different k/v pairs in different formats but nothing I have tried has worked. I have also attempted to reinstall krb5 via homebrew.

I am using an Intel Mac on macOS 12.3.1.

What would be causing Azure Data Studio to not acknowledge my Kerberos Ticket?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add in host file server ip address and server full name (with domain for exmaple  "sqlserver.yourdomain.com")